# Sending "ASC" and "QUOTE TYPE C 1252" commands to AS400 FTP server from Java code

Tags: java, ftp, ibm-midrange, jt400

When I'm using `cmd` to put a file into AS400, after connecting with `ftp`, I went like this:

```
ftp cd /home
ftp prompt 1
ftp ASC
ftp QUOTE TYPE C 1252
ftp mput *
ftp bye
```

Everything is working fine. The file is well encoded. Now, when I'm trying to do the same in Java. I am able to put the file, but it is not well encoded. I'm really stuck. Could someone help me out..

This is my Java code:

```
FTP ftp = this.SABFTPConnection();
ftp.cd(sabConfig.getDirectory());
ftp.setDataTransferType(FTP.BINARY);
ftp.issueCommand("prompt 1");
ftp.issueCommand("ASC");
ftp.issueCommand("QUOTE TYPE C 1252");
File io = new File(file);
boolean done = ftp.put(io, io.getName());
if (done) {
    Log.getLog(SABData.class).info("file "+ io.getName() +" successfuly uploaded");
    collected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FTP.issueCommand`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400FTP.html#issueCommand(java.lang.String)) sends *FTP protocol command* to the server.

- There's no `prompt 1` command in FTP *protocol*. The [`prompt` is `ftp` *client* command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-prompt_1) that turns off interactive prompting. It makes no sense to try to replicate that in your Java code, as it does no prompting.
- There's no `ASC` command in FTP *protocol*. The [`asc[ii]` is `ftp` *client* command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-ascii) that switches to ASCII transfer mode. That goes against the `ftp.setDataTransferType(FTP.BINARY)` in your code.

  Also the `asc` sends `TYPE A` command to the server. And you are sending `TYPE C ...` later, the effect of `asc`/`TYPE A` is cancelled anyway. So the the `asc` is redundant.
- The [`quote` is an `ftp` *client* command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-quote) that sends *its arguments* as a command to the FTP server. So you want to send `TYPE C 1252`, not `QUOTE TYPE C 1252`.

So basically all your `FTP.issueCommand` calls are wrong and they all fail. *You would know, had you checked their return value.*